# How to use super method for a superclass with different attributes

Tags: python

I have a class of characters, they have a name, description, age and size (my attributes).
Then I have a subclass squad that inherits character. Each squad has a name, leader, member1, and member2. (My squad attributes). I am unsure of how to set this up as the two classes share no attributes. All the examples and lessons I find online about class inheritance uses two classes with shared attributes. (such as a furniture class that has the name and price of furniture with a subclass chairs, that has the same name and price, but also has a seat depth, perhaps).

I am just unsure of how my super().**init** should be set up (or if I even need one).

I also need to set up a **str** method for my squad that uses the **str** method from character. I have a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this as well, as I have a squad being passed in as the parameter, so what will the program do when it gets to the part of the super().**str** that tells it to print the character's age, if all it has is my squad name and squad members?

Comment: A "squad" is not a particular type of "character".  There should not be any inheritance relationship here.  A "squad" would simply have a few attributes (or perhaps a single list attribute with a few elements) that are each "character" instances.

Comment: As you describe it, It is better to have member1 and member2 as characters, and no inheritance. Please show your code and show error or problem you have so we can answer with more details.

Comment: Hey Malo, sorry for the lack of information. Honestly I was so confused I had a hard time asking, turns out I was not meant to be using inheritance which was complicating things a lot. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it: it is better to have member1 and member2 as characters, and no inheritance.

A squad is composed of 2 or more charcaters, so it cannot inherint the character class.

For inheritance use case: if you have different types of characters you could have lets say Medics and Soldiers classes inheriting from characters.